# Add-Migration error with EF Core Owned type

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two "owned" types referenced from `ApplicationUser` (which inherits from `IdentityUser`):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace OwnedEntityTest.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public PersonalName Name { get; set; }
        public ValidationToken ValidationToken { get; set; }
    }

    [Owned]
    public class PersonalName
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    [Owned]
    public class ValidationToken
    {
        public int ValidationCode { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExperiationDateUTC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I add a new migration, the scaffolder complains:

> Cannot use table 'IdentityUser' for entity type 'ValidationToken' since it is being used for entity type 'PersonalName' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.

**Is this just a bug, or am I doing something subtly wrong (or not understanding something about owned types)?**

Yes, you can recreate this problem:

1. Create a new project from the `ASP.NET Core Web Application` project template
2. Select `Web Application`
3. Click `Change Authentication` and select `Individual user accounts`
4. In Package Manager Console, enter `update-database` to update the model snapshot.
5. Add the above code to the project
6. In `ApplicationDbContext`, add the reference to ApplicationUsers:
   `public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }`
7. Add a new migration in Package Manager Console:
   `add-migration m_001`
8. Ta dah... you should see the error message

EDIT:

Microsoft has [confirmed that this is a bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14456).

Comment: I have used your code in a brand new project! nothing wrong happened! everything generated perfectly.

Comment: Maybe it's related to another subtle issue I have: When I enter an EF command in the Package Manager Console, I get a warning that I'm not running the latest version of the EF tools.  I've added this comment to the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time, you can use the fluent method to configure this.

1. Remove the `[Owned]` attributes from the data model
2. Configure the relationship by overriding the `OnModelCreating` method on your `ApplicationDbContext`

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(b =>
       {
           b.OwnsOne(e => e.Name);
           b.OwnsOne(e => e.ValidationToken);
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: I pasted your code into my rerpo project, and it changed the symptom but didn't solve it.  Now add-migration complains "The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined."

Comment: @Bob.at.Indigo.Health Sorry about that, you need to call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` in order to properly configure the identity tables. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Almost... That gets me back to the original error message.  But if I remove the [Owned] attributes from the data model then it works.

Comment: Yes, you need to remove Owned attributes. This code replaces them.

Comment: And thank you for a great example of how to configure multiple properties on the same entity.